# Accessing JSON on server using @ModelAttribute("myobject") on spring framework

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have made an spring Crud I am sending form data via post method it is working fine.
my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitobject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveOrUpdateHrEmployee(@ModelAttribute("myObjectForm") @Validated MyObject myObject,
        BindingResult result, Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) 

{
.
.
.    
}
```

But now I want to send form data in JSON, but it is not working. What should I do. I am new to spring and can't understand that how it is making the object of my bean class and getting data from parameters.Need help please 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the code which is not working, the expected behaviour and the actual one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitobject", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public MyObject saveOrUpdateHrEmployee(@RequestBody @Validated MyObject myObject,
    BindingResult result, Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) 

{
.
.
.    
}
```

The above code will work.Let me know for any issues.Spring @RequestBody will convert MyObject into JSON.

The simplest way for my understanding is, the @ModelAttribute will take a query string. so, all the data are being pass to the server through the url.

As for @RequestBody, all the data will be pass to the server through a full JSON body.

Comment: VelNaga its not working. generating error
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult

Comment: Could you remove,@Validated & BindingResult from your method and check whether it is working or not?Meanwhile which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: I don't want responce in json, I am sending request as json.
I tried  params = "application/json" is it correct?

Comment: Then use @RequestBody in modelAttribute

Comment: I updated my answer check and let me know for any issues

Comment: Use either `@ModelAttribute` or `@RequestBody` you cannot use both.

Comment: how to use @RequestBody in modelAttribute?

Comment: thanks I have replace @ModelAttribute("myObjectForm") with @RequestBody now its working

Comment: @SaqibAhmed Also i updated my question about the difference between ModelAttribute & RequestBody.Please up vote if the solution works.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check that you must have property matching between you json string and your pojo class then use below code with requestbody

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitobject", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public String saveOrUpdateHrEmployee(@ModelAttribute("myObjectForm") @RequestBody MyObject myObject,
            BindingResult result, Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) 

    {
    .
    .
    .    
    }
```

more thing to be note down is your validation binding exception might be because of validation issue try to refer [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800734/org-springframework-validation-beanpropertybindingresult)